# log4net isn't logging at start, starts after a little time

Tags: log4net

We've been using log4net in a .net console app. It used to log everything to console and SQL from the first entry. All of a sudden, the logger doesn't write to our SQL until much later, and it's weird, considering:

```
Logger.Info("my message won't log")
Logger.Info("my message will log")
```

it won't log the first but logs the second. Appears to happen every time at the same lines of code, still verifying that. I debugged, stopped at the first logger, used immediate window and log a message and that worked. Can't seem to see why.

But all the meanwhile everything is being logged to the console fine!

Thoughts on what could have happened or why?

Code for custom appender

```
namespace Dsmt.Logging
{
    public class HistoryPatternLayout : PatternLayout
    {
        public HistoryPatternLayout()
        {
            AddConverter(new ConverterInfo
            {
                Name = "migrationHistory",
                Type = typeof(MigrationHistoryConverter)
            });
        }
    }

    public class MigrationHistoryConverter : PatternConverter
    {
        protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, object state)
        {
            if (state == null)
            {
                writer.Write(SystemInfo.NullText);
                return;
            }
            var loggingEvent = state as LoggingEvent;
            var historyInfo = loggingEvent!= null ? loggingEvent.MessageObject as HistoryLoggerInfo : null;
            if (historyInfo == null)
            {
                writer.Write(SystemInfo.NullText);
                return;
            }
            switch (this.Option.ToLower())
            {
                case "migrationhistoryid" :
                    writer.Write(historyInfo.MigrationHistoryId);
                    break;
                case "itemid" :
                    writer.Write(historyInfo.ItemID);
                    break;
                case "success" :
                    writer.Write(historyInfo.Success);
                    break;
                case "message" :
                    writer.Write(historyInfo.Message);
                    break;
                case "itemdatetime" :
                    writer.Write(historyInfo.ItemDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                    break;
                case "newlocation":
                    writer.Write(historyInfo.NewLocation);
                    break;

                default :
                    writer.Write(SystemInfo.NullText);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class HistoryLoggerInfo
    {
        public string MigrationHistoryId { get; set; }
        public string ItemID { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime ItemDateTime { get; set; }

        public string NewLocation { get;set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
            //var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new Log4NetDateTimeConverter());
            return serializeObject;
        }

        public class Log4NetDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
        {
            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-13);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you run it with a Sql profiler running to see if the SQL statements are being sent? I remember once having an issue when log4net was attempting to use prepared SQL statement handles that hadn't been created yet, which the server was rejecting.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, I see the first 2 log entries in profiler, and it's using exec sp_prepexec, meanwhile the entries that I get to see in SQL are all using exec sp_execute

Comment: I misread. It appears the first entry is when we are calling LogManager.GetLogger. The 2nd entry is the logger.Info we call right after that. Then there are other logger.Infos that are missing until the logs are picked up again

Comment: That's very odd. so it starts out working and then stops and then starts again? If you want oddball suggestions then: have you checked that the value if IsInfoEnabled is still true on the logger during the failed calls? Are you configuring log4net more than once during program execution? Are you using custom appenders or other classes or doing any runtime configuration changes?

Comment: What is your buffer size set to for the appender?

Comment: Buffer is 5 for appender.

Comment: IsInfoEnabled is true. We're using an appender, not sure how custom though? I wasn't the guy who built it

Comment: Can you post the appender code?

Comment: added History Appender code

Comment: Nothing there jumps out as wrong - is there anything in the [log4net debug output](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/)?

Comment: If the buffer is set to five they you wont see any results in the db until you have 5 events logged.

Comment: This problem isn't that we're getting them late. We are never getting them in SQL. We do in the console however

Comment: I discovered that the first 2 batches never get logged. The size was set to 25, and we never got the first 50. I switched it to 1, and we're now missing the first 2 logging events.